# Is there a way to perform operations on the same field in different list structs with the same function?

Tags: c, pointers, struct, syntax

Is there a way to access the same field in different list structs with the same function?

For example, like the max function that can be used with different types:

```
#define MAX(a,b) (((a)>(b))?(a):(b))
```

Then suppose I have two different list types:

```
typedef struct lst1{
    struct lst1 * head;
    ...
} LST1;

typedef struct lst2{
    struct lst2 * head;
    ...
} LST2;
```

Is there a function that would work similarly to the `max` function like this maybe?

```
#define isempty(x) ((x->head==NULL) ? 1 : 0)
```

PS: `isempty` didn't work for me, this is the sample code and error I got:

```
List lst;
lst.head = NULL;
List * a = &lst;
int a = isempty(a);

error C2040: 'a' : 'int' differs in levels of indirection from 'List *'
```

Comment: Well you can do something similar to inheritance in c++.

Comment: Have you tried your `isempty`? It looks, at first glance, as if it could work. If it didn't, what happened?

Comment: @Politank-Z it didn't work, see the edit.

Comment: @iharob c++ also has template functions (which I suppose could work here) but unfortunately I'm restricted to c only.

Comment: You're declaring `a` as both a `List *` and as an `int`. If you use different identifiers, do you get the same error?

Comment: @kuhaku I didn't say that the programming language should be c++, the question is tagged c, I just said that one can emulate inheritance.

Comment: @Politank-Z oh damn... Hmm I need to test it now if it works properly.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Suppose you have two lists, then you could define them as follows

```
#include <stdio.h>

struct GenericList
 {
    struct GenericList *commonField;
 };

struct FirstList
 {
    struct FirstList *commonField;
    int               firstListField;
 };

struct SecondList
 {
    struct SecondList *commonField;
    int                secondListField;
 };

int isempty(struct GenericList *list)
 {
    return ((list != NULL) && (list->commonField != NULL));
 }

int main(void)
 {
    struct FirstList  firstList;
    struct SecondList secondList;

    memset(&firstList, 0, sizeof(firstList));
    memset(&secondList, 0, sizeof(secondList));

    if (isempty((struct GenericList *)&firstList) == 0)
        printf("The list is empty ... \n");
    if (isempty((struct  GenericList *)&secondList) == 0)
        printf("The list is empty ... \n");

    return 0;
 }
```

As long as the begining of the structure definitions match, you can do it for more fields, that's why it's like inheritance in c++.

Comment: I tried to do this with `listlen` function: http://pastebin.com/EB2u23JV but it seems that when the `curr` pointer reaches what is supposed to be `NULL` it isn't `NULL` but just junk, resulting in an error. Any idea on how to make it recognize the last pointer as `NULL`? also, why does it happen?